# How to upload file using ajax and file extension validation using ajax in freeform?

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads, ajax, validation

I'm using Freeform 4.0.11. I have a form, which i want to upload file using ajax and also check file extension validation using ajax.

Except file upload field, every fields value are submitted, but i can't got attachment file.

So, How i can upload my file using AJAX and how to i can check file extension validation using AJAX.

FYI:

Freeform 4.0.11

ExpressionEngine  2.5.5

Thanks!
Jignesh

Comment: Did you get this working? I need to do something similar (show the uploaded file before user hits submit). Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am also trying to find a way to do this and have not found any help on this.